# how to add time in java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java

How to add 3 hours to the time that store in `java.sql.Timestamp` by not using the deprecated API?

I use the below code, but it doesn't work.

```
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(old + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 3));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Calendar for date manipulation:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: You can use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` to skip the `Date` conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `old` is a `Timestamp`; your code is close. You just need to convert the `old` timestamp to a millisecond value first. Do:

```
Timestamp later = new Timestamp(old.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 3));
```

Neither `getTime()` nor the `Timestamp(long)` constructor are deprecated.

Note that all of this information is readily available in the [`Timestamp` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).